# Wrapping all children-elements until next div/section-element

Tags: jquery

I try to wrap the elements of a content-container by clicking on it. The first difficulty for me is that all elements should be wrapped until the next div-container. In this example there are only p-elements, but there could also be some ul-lists or tables.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <div class="level_2">
        <div class="content">
            <p>Another Text</p>
            <p>Another Text</p>
            <p>Another Text</p>
            <p>Another Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This should become this by clicking on the first content-container.

```
<div class="content">
<div class="mark_this">
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
</div>
    <div class="level_2">
        <div class="content">
            <p>Another Text</p>
            <p>Another Text</p>
            <p>Another Text</p>
            <p>Another Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.content').click(function() { // should be something like $('.content').children().click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('div, section').addBack().wrapAll("<div class='mark_this' />");
});
```

Because the .content-container are nested, I guess it would be better to check for a click on any element in a .content-container and get the parent element. But the above described difficulty is the same for me.

Comment: Do you really need to add the `div`? Might setting the extra class on the div clicked on provide the same effect? `$("body").on("click", ".content", function() { $(this).toggleClass("mark_this"); });`

Comment: I think I need the new div. For example the first .content has the second .content also included, because it is nested. But I just need the elements before the second .content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
$('.content').children().not("div").click(function() {  
 if(0 === $(this).parents("div.mark_this").length)    {
  $(this).parent("div").children().nextUntil('div').addBack().not('div').wrapAll("<div class='mark_this' />");}
});
```

Working Demo: [Wrap children until next div](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/3cx994tz/1/)

Comment: I think you have to take the child-elements as target for the click. As both .content are nested, there will be two .mark_it-container as you click on "Another text", but there should only be one container. Clicking on "Some text" works perfectly, as there is no parent-content-container

Comment: @user3142695 Yes you're right, should've checked in detail before posting. Fixed some issues in the answer and updated the demo. Should work now like intended.